# TYPO3: configure TCA to use existing table

Tags: model, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to use an existing table in my extension. This table will be used only in read-only mode. In fact my extension will only use two fields: *uid* and *title*.
Extension builder added *tx_extbase_type* field to this table. I don't need this field because my extension wouldn't store any data in this table and it must handle with data already existing in the table.

So the question is: how can I configure TCA to use this table?

Here is the block of *ext_tables.php* dealing with this table. Definition of *tx_extbase_type*-field is already removed.

```
$tmp_myext_columns = array(

    'title' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_targettable.title',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim,required'
        ),
    ),
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tx_someext_domain_model_targettable',$tmp_myext_columns);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['types']['Tx_MyExt_TargetTable']['showitem'] = $TCA['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['types']['1']['showitem'];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['types']['Tx_MyExt_TargetTable']['showitem'] .= ',--div--;LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_targettable,';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['types']['Tx_MyExt_TargetTable']['showitem'] .= 'title';

--> $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['columns'][$TCA['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['ctrl']['type']]['config']['items'][] = array('LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_someext_domain_model_targettable.tx_extbase_type.Tx_MyExt_TargetTable','Tx_MyExt_TargetTable');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_someext_domain_model_targettable', $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['ctrl']['type'],'','after:' . $TCA['tx_someext_domain_model_targettable']['ctrl']['label']);
```

I tried to delete the line marked with **--->** (containing **tx_extbase_type**-field). In this case `repository->findAll()` always gives me records with empty strings instead of real titles. Though the number of records and their ids in query result are correct!

I'm using TYPO3 CMS 6.2.19

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the part where you have to map your model to an existing table through typoscript (I suggest you put it in your setup.txt):

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.[my_model_class_path] {
mapping {
    tableName = [existing_extbase_table]
}
```

Cheers,
Olivier

Comment: Thanks! That was a good tip! In my ext_typoscript_setup.txt  
in the model mapping there was a line `recordType = Tx_MyVendor_TargetTable`. After I deleted this line it works.